# Port Forwarding from Modem->Router->PC

Tags: portforwarding

So I have an xfinity Modem I pay lease monthly, and although the xfinity modem itself has a built-in 4-port router capability with wifi, my room is too far away from the modem so i bought a TPlink router, connected the router from my modem with an approximately 70 foot long cat5 cable, and hooked up my local machines from there. That's fine. But, I have a Nodejs server I built and I can run it directly from my PC. But, I don't know how to port-forward from my router to my modem to the internet. Is there some kind of double port forwarding i can do? I went though my modem's control panel and the router's and still can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Why do you use two routers? If you have the long cable, why can't you just hook it up to the built-in router on the modem-router combo?

Comment: This question is not a programming question, should be closed as off topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your modem's configuration put the second router as the DMZ IP.  Then on the second router you can port-forward whatever ports you want to your Nodejs.